# What finish can I put on my pallet floor to fill cracks?

Tags: floor, finish

What finish can I put on my pallet floor to fill in cracks and have an even, thick top coating?

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange. A photo of the floor would help us guide you as a "pallet" floor could be several different types and some ideas may take you down the wrong path because we have a different idea of "pallet"

Answer (score 3):

If you built a floor out of pallet boards I would expect that the floor would be uneven, have cracks between boards and rough surfaces. That style is pretty much what you get with this type of material!!

There is not much that you could do with it except to rip it out and go with something more conventional. You may be able to cover it with a floor leveling material if all the pallet boards are solidly nailed in but then you are still looking at having to install some new floor surface over that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is salvaged wood from pallets, you can sand it all down and groove out all the cracks.  Then, you can cut little "Dutchmen" to fit those larger cracks, glue them in, and plane that level with the floor.

If the larger cracks are sealed, you could then coat the floor with a polyurethane or something similar.

Comment: I wanted to suggest +isherwood's comment below, but he's right, crystal epoxy is crazy expensive to do a floor with.

Answer (score 1):

[Table epoxy](http://www.uscomposites.com/kk121.html) comes to mind, but it certainly wouldn't be a cheap solution. Like Michael Karas said, you have to expect a rustic look with pallet wood.

Answer (score 1):

As I have actually used pallet wood as my entire house's flooring. Save the wood shavings from cutting the wood, and mix it with a wood glue and mix in the shavings. There is actually a brand that works great but I dont remember it. Take the shaving and glue mixture and fill in as much cracks and pin hole or screw holes you can. Dry and then sand to desired thickness. Seal with poly/epoxy/or a stain/sealant. Then you good to go

Comment: By "shavings", do you actually mean "sawdust"?

Answer (score 0):

Pallet wood probably has some variance in thickness.  Also there has to be some slight warping.  I really really heavy coat of polyurethane could even out the walking area and fill in the gaps.  This is provided the subfloor could stop the liquid flow from seeping to whatever is below it.